# Exclude terms in replacement rules application

Tags: replacement, polynomials, rule

Suppose I consider a polynomial of type

```
A=B x y + C x
```

and define a replacement rule

```
rrule=(# /. x y -> 1) &;
```

The result of the application of this rule on the polynomial A trivially will be

```
In[]:=A//rrule
Out[]:=B+C x
```

As far as I understood about those kind of replacement rules, `rrule` will try to act also on the monomial `C x`, but it has no effect as it doesn't recognize the desired  pattern. Currently, I'm working with much more complicated replacement rules and I noticed that the most time-demanding part of my code is indeed the search for the patterns, not the replacement rule itself. Basically, from the example above `B x y//rrule` runs much faster than `B x y + C x//rrule` (it looks like, `rrule` tries to act noticing the presence of `x`  in the monomial and this is time-demanding).

So I'm wondering, is there a way to exclude "a priori" some terms from the application of replacement rules? Namely define rules such that

```
B x y + C x//rrule===(B x y//rrule) + C x
```

Comment: Why are you defining your rule as a pure function and not simply as a rule? That is: ``rrule = x y -> 1; b x y + c x /. rrule`` It is hard to predict for your specific purpose, but for your small example, the timing difference is [significant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV7qv.png).

Comment: You define the rule too complicated. Try: `rrule =  x y -> 1` and then `A/.rrule` To eliminate superfluous matches you may try something like: `rrule = z : x y -> 1 /: ! FreeQ[z, y]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instinct to define a pure function to make the replacement is not wrong. *Mathematica* provides an operator form of `ReplaceAll` that can be used with `MapAt` to target specific parts of an expression.

Consider these definitions:

```
a = b x y + c x     (*  c x + b x y  *)
rules = {x -> U, y -> V};
```

Note that the $c x$ term is the *first term* in expression $a$.  So, we can apply the replacement rule to the $c x$ term only like this

```
MapAt[ReplaceAll[rules], a, 1]   (*  c U + b x y  *)
```

to the *second term* like this

```
MapAt[ReplaceAll[rules], a, 2]   (*  b U V + c x  *)
```

and to *both terms* like

```
MapAt[ReplaceAll[rules], a, {{1}, {2}}]  (*  c U + b U V  *)
```

But, this doesn't really answer the question How to Exclude Specific Terms? from the replacement.